# Python 3: how to compare two things

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5

This my code and it work well. But is there another way to write this code?

```
def getCorrectAnswer(self, answer):
  return answer == self.get_canswer()
```

Comment: what's wrong with this one?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it. I just want to know if there is different way to write it that involve more then one or two step?

Comment: Of course, you can obfuscate the code in a million different ways. There are even automated tools that do that. Please make you question more specific.

Comment: What will be another way to compare `answer to self.get_canswer()` using `if statement`?

Comment: @user5517779: have you tried the is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return answer in (self.get_canswer(), )

return {self.get_canswer(): 'this is the correct answer'}.get(answer, False)

return [self.get_canswer()].pop() == answer
```

Note:  None of these should be used in production code.